# ¿Como usar Material Design en API menor a 21?

Tags: java, android

Como bien dice la pregunta, quiero saber si se hay alguna manera de usar Material Design en alguna API menor a 21(que por lo que tengo entendido en esta version se publicó Material Design), y si es así, ¿como?
Otra pregunta es acerca de cuando y cuando no usar lo `android:` en layout's y demás.

Comment: Yo uso normalmente en mis apps SDK min 16 con el Android Studio ya se encarga de crear los recursos requeridos para compatiblidad, pero hay cosas como el ripple "efecto sobre el botón" que solo es compatible en versión Android L y superior

Answer (score 1):

Puedes agregar a tus dependencias de `Gradle` para versiones menores a `21`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3"
}
```

En adición usas como tema base por ejemplo:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
</style>
```

Personalmente he trabajado con apps entre versiones de APIS 15 y 19 y no he tenido problemas.

Te recomiendo que te des una vuelta por este [blog](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/) donde se explica muy bien como implementar ***Material Design*** para dispositivos pre-lollipops, suerte